# How to include a PHP file which contains $this and gives "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context"

Tags: php, this, this-pointer

I want to include a file with the path `/home/public_html/dir5/file5.php` in my php file with path `/home/public_html/dir1/file1.php` but the problem I get is

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/public_html/dir5/file5.php:2

The content of file5.php is as follows:

```
<?php
 if ( !$this->is_users_rating_disabled() ):
    $score = isset( $this->users_data['overall'] ) ? $this->users_data['overall'] : 0;
    $count = isset( $this->users_data['count'] ) ? $this->users_data['count'] : 0;
    $theme = $this->template_field('template_theme', true);
    $maximum_score = $this->template_field('template_maximum_score', true);
     $revOver = $score;
?>
```

I've read other posts it might be because of the `$this` like it says in the error log, how can I transform my code to work?

I saw some examples you can transform from:

```
$this->$db->etc
```

to:

```
$db = get_instance();
$db->etc
```

something like that, but in my case I have `$this->users_data['overall']` and `$this->template_field('template_maximum_score', true);` for example, how can I transform that? Thanks!

Update: is_users_rating_disabled() is defined like below:

```
public function is_users_rating_disabled()
{

    $auth = $this->preferences_field('preferences_authorization', true);

    if ($auth == 'disabled' || $this->review_field('review_disable_user_rating', true) == 'yes') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In the end I only want to use $revOver variable from file5.php in file1.php , I tried using GLOBALS['revover'] = $revOver; set in file5.php and using it in file1.php but it's not working, is there any way besides including file5.php in file1.php to use that variable?

Comment: How is `is_users_rating_disabled()` defined?

Comment: is_users_rating_disabled() is defined like below:

public function is_users_rating_disabled()
{

    $auth = $this->preferences_field('preferences_authorization', true);

    if ($auth == 'disabled' || $this->review_field('review_disable_user_rating', true) == 'yes') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

Comment: `public` implies that the function is actually a class _method_. It is a semantic difference, but it is important to note. Classes are a way to isolate and protect code. Inside a class `$this` is used to access protected portions, but only the classes author can use it. Rewriting code to not use `$this` doesn’t really make sense unless the bigger picture can be seen.

Comment: In the end I only want to use $revOver variable from file5.php in file1.php , I tried using GLOBALS['revover'] = $revOver; set in file5.php and using it in file1.php but it's not working, is there any way besides including file5.php in file1.php to use that variable?

Comment: no one knows how to do this?

Comment: still searching on this... still digging ...